# complement image rotate and zoom in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

i want to make a image viewer, it can display image with rotate function, and zoom in and out with slider , but now i have no idea about rotate and zoom ,please help，xaml code ：

```
        <Viewbox>
        <Image Source="{Binding JpgImageSource}">
        </Image>
        </Viewbox>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Width="100">
        <Button Content="open" Width="80" Margin="5" Command="{Binding OpenJpgImgCmd}"/>
        <Button Content="leftrotate90" Width="80" Margin="5" Command="{Binding LeftRotate90Cmd}"></Button>
        <Button Content="rightrotate90" Width="80" Command="{Binding}"/>
        <Slider Orientation="Vertical" Height="100" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
```

behind code is as below，i have changed path to bitmapsource, now how to complement the rotate command and zoom command

```
            OpenFileDialog ofdimg=new OpenFileDialog();
            ofdimg.Filter = "Image Files (*.jpg;*.jpep)|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.bmp;*.png;*.tif;*.gif;|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
            ofdimg.ShowDialog();
            string ImgPath = ofdimg.FileName;
            BitmapSource bm = new BitmapImage(new Uri(ImgPath));
            JpgImageSource = bm;
```

Answer (score 3):

Image control does not know how to parse an Image. You should Bind it to a BitmapSource. 
After you quire the path for the image simply do `BitmapSource source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(path));` and bind the Image control to the BitmapSource.